# render custom 404 in nginx or something else if 404 doesn't exist

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'd like to host HTML files uploaded by users and I need to display custom 404 if they provided it, or display my own 404 otherwise.

Sample workflow:

1. visitor tries to access example.com/pages/page1.html
2. `pages/page1.html` does not exists but $user has uploaded `404.html` so display it
3. $user has not provided `404.html` so display simple message myself

So far I have covered the steps 1 & 2 but cannot make the logic for last one.

My /simplified/ config:

```
# each user has their own storage path etc
# just to illustrate
map $host $user {
    dog.example.com             group/1/2/3;
    cat.example.com             group/4/5/1;
    dog-want-cookie.example.com group/9/9/9;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name ~^(?<vhost>[^.]*)\.example\.com$;

    root /sites/$user;

    location / {        
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html @not_found;
    }

    location @not_found {
        internal;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
    }
}
```

Not sure where to "invoke" a config for my own error "page".

```
location @my404 {
    return 404 "Page not found.";
}
```

I'm using Nginx 1.19.3 on Debian.

Comment: Are you intending to write your own `404.html` or use Nginx default 404 response as the fallback?

Comment: I'd like to use my own 404 for the fallback. best if this can be achieved by simply returning the error with message (to bypass template lookup/render), as per `location @my404` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `error_page` to invoke the named location rather than `try_files`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

For example:

```
error_page 404 @not_found;

location / {        
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
}
```

---

Use `try_files` to test the existence of the `404.html` file.

For example:

```
location @not_found {
    try_files /404.html /fallback404.html =404;
}
```

You do not need to mark named locations as `internal`, as they cannot be accessed externally.

In the above example, the `fallback404.html` file is in the same document root. The `=404` is necessary for the syntax, but is never reached as the second file always exists. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

---

To use a fallback `404.html` file in a different document root, you can cascade two named locations.

For example:

```
location @not_found {
    try_files /404.html @fallback;
}
location @fallback {
    root /path/to/fallback/files;
    try_files /404.html =404;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can replace the content of the `@fallback` location with your `return` statement.

For example:

```
location @fallback {
    return 404 "Page not found.";
}
```